# 'max_questions' for user 'root' has exceeded

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql

Accidentally change settings on mysql server (local LAMP), and now i have this:

```
ERROR 1226 (42000): User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 1)
```

Can't use any query, also mysqladmin flush-privileges or reload. 
Any way to change privileges? Config-files maybe? (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can only limit the the *rate* at which you can execute queries - specifically [the maximum number of queries per hour](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-resources.html). So, if you have set this for the root user, you just need to wait for another 55 minutes, then you should be able to:

```
 update mysql.user set max_questions = 0 where user = 'root';
 flush privileges;
```

(not sure if the second instructions requires a one hour wait - if it does you can restart the DBMS).

If its the global limit you have set, then change it in your my.ini file (max_questions=0) and restart the DBMS from the OS.